# How to pass multiple data from EditText(Main Activity) to ListView(Another Activity )

Tags: android, android-studio

1. MainActivity has a listview and edit button. When the Edit button is clicked, it jumps to EditAddItem page.
2. EditAddItem class has a edit text and button, every time when I type something on edit text, and then click Save, the data will be passed to MainActivity and it will be shown in listview. Can someone give me some tips?

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//This is code part of EditAddItem Class
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_add_item);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditAddItem.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("text", editText.getText().toString());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }

    });

         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//Code part of MainActivity
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView);
        addItemEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add("item one");
        items.add("item two");


        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               openEditItemView();
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: You want the edittext data to receive in MainActivity, right?

Comment: I want to pass the data from edittext to the listview in the MainActivity. For example, in EditAddItem, I typed 123 in etext, then I click the save button.  When I back to MainActivity, 123 should be displayed in listview.

Comment: override the method onActivityResult in MainActivity, receive your data and then pass it to your ArrayAdapter and setAdapter. It will display your data.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: I just follow your code, but it seems like does not work. When I click the save button, nothing will be passed to the main activity

Comment: In onActivityResult, what value you get for the string (editTextConttent) ? It it null ?

Comment: `How to pass multiple data from EditText(Main Activity) to ListView(Another Activity )` No! `How to pass multiple data from EditText(Another Activity) to ListView(Main Activity )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your logic is switched. You should `startActivityForResult` from MainActivity and finish with result from EditAddItemActiity. Then in MainActivity you should override `onActivityResult` to get text passed from EditAddItemActivity.

You should do something like this:

MainActivity.java

```java
    public static final int EDIT_ADD_ITEM_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final String EXTRA_EDIT_ADD_ITEM = "EXTRA_EDIT_ADD_ITEM";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//Code part of MainActivity
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView);
     addItemEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
     items = new ArrayList<String>();
     items.add("item one");
     items.add("item two");


     itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

     listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);


     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditAddItem.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_ADD_ITEM_RESULT);
        }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == EDIT_ADD_ITEM_REQUEST) {
                String name = data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_EDIT_ADD_ITEM);
                updateList(name);
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateList(String name) {
        itemsAdapter.add(name);
    }
}
```

EditAddItem.java

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//This is code part of EditAddItem Class
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_add_item);
 editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_EDIT_ADD_ITEM, editText.getText().toString());
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();

     }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

override onActivityResult() in the first activity, you need to do the proper implementation of passing data as a bundle from the second activity and get the data and update the list and call notify data change.

Comment: Could please give more details?

Comment: can you share second activity code also, how are you passing data back to first activity some code is missing in your description to understand your issue better.

Answer (score 0):

in your MainActivity(The same activity where you have ListView)-

```
        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditAddItem.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

// also override below method

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode ==0 && resultCode== RESULT_OK && data != null)
    {

        Sting editTextContent = data.getStringExtra("editText"); // your data
        
        //now put data into your ListView
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add(editTextContent);
        
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    }
}
```

In your EditAddItem activity(The editText activity) -

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString()))
        {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra("editText", editText.getText().toString());
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
        } else
        { 
           Toast.makeText(this, "EditText is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```